# passing a function for validating numbers only vb.net

Tags: vb.net

so i have this text field where i would like to only enter numberic values 
i am able to do this with this piece of code

```
   .KeyPress //using a keypress event 

            If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso
                e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If

        End Sub
```

the above code works fine but i am wondering if i can pass it as a function and call that function whenever i need it 
somthing like so:

```
private Function Numbers_Only()

    If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso
                    e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
                    e.Handled = True
                End If
End Function
```

But it doesn't seem to work can somebody show me the correct way of passing this through the function please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare this as a Sub as it doesn't return any value and modifies the arguments passed in.

```
Private Sub Numbers_Only(e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively do it as a function:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    e.Handled = Numbers_only(e.KeyCode)
End Sub

Private Function Numbers_only(keyChar As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
    Return (keyChar < System.Windows.Forms.Keys.D0 OrElse keyChar > System.Windows.Forms.Keys.D9) AndAlso keyChar <> System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Back
End Function
```

Comment: thanks i guess i will use the `Sub` thanks for the answer :)

Comment: so when i will call the `Sub` will it be like this `Numbers_Only(e)`

Comment: Yes. You may need to change the type of the parameter depending on if you're using keypress or keydown events.

Comment: Nice i am using a `KeyPress` Event